# WPF ListView shrink contents to fit container

Tags: wpf

I have a ListView that displays `x` items. It's defined like so;

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyCard" DataType="models:MyModel">
            <StackPanel Background="{Binding BackgroundColour}"
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                       Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding MyType, Converter={StaticResource EnumDisplayNameConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static myNamespace:MyViewModel.Options}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyCard}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Unfortunately, the items still flow off the viewable area and get clipped, like so;

[image: Clipped]

I was expecting that the items would resize to fit the bounds, but this is obviously not the case. I've tried adding a `ViewBox` to the `DataTemplate` to resolve this but it's still not working as expected.

The images are all 300px x 300px and I've tried setting `MaxWidth`/`MaxHeight` on the `StackPanel`, `ViewBox` and `Image` but it still flows off the "end".

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside inner template, do not use StackPanel as it's growing bounds automatically to accommodate content (and would overlap ListBox scrollable area as well). If you expect auto-resizing, use Grid instead or set exact sizes on inner controls like Image etc.

Comment: Even manually setting the `Height` of the `WrapPanel`, there's still clipping. It's almost like it's something internal to the `WrapPanel` that's still getting an infinite height?